# SQL: display children and brothers/sisters

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have a database that basically stores a family tree made of several families.

I have two tables:

1. "persons": id, name, lname
2. "relationships": parent, child

Displaying all parents is ok, I did this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.fname, p.lname
FROM persons p
INNER JOIN relationships ON p.id = relationships.p
INNER JOIN persons c ON c.id = relationships.c;
```

But how could I display comprehensively each child and its respective brothers/sisters?

I tried a select within a select among many things but it's not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c1.name, 
    c1.lname,
    (
    SELECT 
        c2.firstname, 
        c2.lastname 
    FROM 
        persons p2 
    INNER JOIN relations  ON p2.id = relations.parent 
    INNER JOIN persons c2 ON c2.id = relations.child
    WHERE 
        p.id = p2.id
    ) 
FROM 
    persons p
INNER JOIN relations  ON p.id  = relations.parent 
INNER JOIN persons c1 ON c1.id = relations.child;
```

I think I'm on the wrong path.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a self join:

```
select r.child, r2.child as sibling
from relationships r join
     relationships r2
     on r.parent = r2.parent and
        r.child <> r2.child
order by r.child, r2.child;
```

For the names from the other table you need more joins:

```
select p.*, p2.*
from relationships r join
     relationships r2
     on r.parent = r2.parent and
        r.child <> r2.child join
     persons p
     on p.id = r.child join
     persons p2
     on p2.id = r2.child
order by r.child, r2.child;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to edit your code so that it retrieves names instead of id's. I'll come back to you when I get there.

Comment: Thank you ! I need to analyse your code because I don't get it yet of course but it's all I needed so that I can understand how it all works. Thanks !